# execute events read from JSON

Tags: java, string, execute, awtrobot

I am reading two things from a JSON file:

```
actionOnPress:"robot.KeyPress(e)"
```

(robot being a     java.awt.robot instance) and

```
event:"KeyEvent.VK_4"
```

I want to execute

```
robot.KeyPress(KeyEvent.VK_4)
```

what is the easiest way (best without needing to download libraries) to execute this? This code is supposed to also work with robot.mousePress and robot.mouseMove etc.

I already tried different things with ScriptEngine, but none of it seems to work.

Thank you very much, Kamik423

EDIT: should be universal. The user should be able to specify different events like FOR EXAMPLE robot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved it myself. Here is the code:

```
package test;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class executor extends JFrame {

    String import1 = "java.awt.Robot";
    String import2 = "java.awt.event.KeyEvent";
    String setup1 = "r = new Robot";


    String executionType = "r.keyPress(event)";
    String event = "KeyEvent.VK_4";


    private JTextField textField;

    static ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    static ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    public executor() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setBounds(100,100,100,100);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
                try {
                    engine.eval("importClass(" + import1 + ")");
                    engine.eval("importClass(" + import2 + ")");

                    engine.eval(setup1);

                    engine.eval(executionType.replaceAll("event", event));

                } catch (ScriptException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        textField.setColumns(10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        executor ex = new executor();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```